# Options for token storage and refresh in SPAs

Tags: angular, reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, owasp

I've been reading Aaron Parecki's draft of browser-based apps' (meaning SPAs like those developed with React or Angular) authentication best practices with OAuth 2 as well as OWASP security guidelines, and it left me really confused:

1. The draft of the RFC mentions rotating refresh tokens. Now how would I do that while adhering to stateless constraint of REST? Do I include some digest of a random string in the cookie and the refresh token as well and check if they are equal?
2. What is the correct way (or rather, some of the more secure ways) of storing refresh tokens in the browser? I've checked okta's JS auth library, and it uses `localStorage` by default, which OWASP guidelines recommend against. Does it have some kind of extra protection? Should I put some extra digest in it and also put it in a cookie and match them?
3. OWASP recommends session IDs should be completely opaque to the client, but if we use JWT, doesn't it violate this principle? Does this mean I should always encrypt my JWTs with a symmetric cipher?

Some references:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04#section-4
- https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md
- https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java.md
- https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.md

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TRADITIONAL SPA FLOW**

In the traditional SPA flow it was standard to use [iframes to silently renew tokens](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal).

Meanwhile access tokens were best stored only in memory and should also be short lived. There were still threats of capturing tokens in transit.

**2021 UPDATE**

There are two big changes to browsers that are related to SPA token refresh:

- Browsers drop third party cookies aggressively, meaning that traditional SPA token refresh no longer works reliably (eg in the Safari browser)
- Browser cookies security has become stronger via `SameSite=strict` cookies, and concerns about [XSS threats (video)](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html) have increased

**BACK END FOR FRONT END**

So it is now recommended to store refresh tokens in HTTP only encrypted `SameSite=strict` cookies. This is best done in an API driven manner, to avoid impacting the web architecture. See this [blog post](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/) for some up-to-date best practices and links to resources including a React code example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've heard about this solution before, but I think what I failed to mention is that I had primarily same origin deployment in mind. Am I correct that the hidden iframe trick relies on a secure, http-only cookie to work? But then, if we're talking about a same-domain deployment, wouldn't all that be unnecessary? The IETF draft mentions that in this case cookies would be more secure, BUT it might make sense to implement everything with more conventional tokens for the sake of an easier potential migration. What do you think is the best course of action in that case?

Comment: Also, I'm interested in the question more from the side of a full-stack developer who gets to manage both front-end and back-end. I just used okta's libraries as an example of something I expected to find good practices in.

Comment: My preference is for the SPA itself to be cookieless (its back end issues no cookies - even though the browser may use a cookie from the Authorization Server). Token based SPAs have the best [future hosting and extensibility options](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-requirements/) I think. In the early days you could host both together on the same domain, such as https://mycompany.com/spa and https://mycompany.com/api. You could still do this in a full stack developer manner, while keeping concerns separated.

Comment: Having said that, there is a cost and learning curve to implementing a token based architecture and introducing an Authorization Server. A solution based on same site cookies would be secure and may be much lower cost - and therefore more achievable. I would still logically separate the API and SPA though.